# Switching Hosting provider and taking my Gmail account with me

Tags: g-suite, gmail, dreamhost

My site is currently hosted on Dreamhost and I used their control panel to set up a GMail account of the form :  me@mydomain.com

I am about to move everything over to Heroku.

The question:  Is my email account tied to Dreamhost in anyway?  I didn't have to set up any MX records when I created the account, and was actually redirected to the google-apps control panel to set most of it up so I'm guessing that I'll be ok here as the domain name is going to remain the same.  I'm just a bit concerned that google might have associated my account with Dreamhost's Name servers or something.....

I am prepared to go through the validation process again, but it would be nice to know in advance if this is likely to be required.

Thanks in advance, I apologise if this isn't the place for this kind of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being familiar with Dreamhost's setup I would assume if it's a Google apps account you will just need to add the proper MX records at your new host.  You can use some simple tools like dig to find out your current MX records and see how "attached" they are to Dreamhost.  If this apps account came with your hosting account as a Dreamhost feature you would likely get the best answer from their support staff.

Comment: hey thanks - you were right - I've managed to move over and email is working fine.  took less than 5 mins.